# Spring Restful Services : how to append "String type " in response to json

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb, rest

I need to retrieve data from 3 Mongodb collection:

- Airport
- Resort
- City

Array of json documents of resorts and airports, matching the search string with :

1. name of resort or airport
2. name of city to which resorts / airports belong.

There are one json object for resorts, one for airports, and one for city.

The json documents will contain the name of the category (resorts , airports, city_name), and an array of matching resorts / airports.

Request mapping : `/api/destination/resortairport/Lon`

parameters: `Lon`

Response:

```
[ {type: "airport", "airport":
    [
        {"airportcode":"LCY", "airportname": "London City Airport"},
        {"airportcode":"LHR", "airportname": "London Heathrow"},
        {"airportcode":"LTN", "airportname": "London Luton"}
    ]},
  {type: "resort", "resort":[
        {"resortname": "London E Postcodes", "indexid":26447}, 
        {"resortname": "London W Postcodes", "indexid":26448},
        {"resortname": "London N Postcodes", "indexid":26449},
        {"resortname": "London S Postcodes", "indexid":264450}
]}]
```

Comment: Can you please tell me whats the issue you are facing?

Comment: formatting text code, typo correction

Comment: how to append "type"(its a string variable) in response to json. type - must display their collection names